# Tests for Django Channels consumers: "No reply_channel sent to consumer"

Tags: django, django-testing, django-channels

I am using *Django Channels* with the `@channel_session_user` decorator (for access to Django's session data).

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    # creates group names like "group-1"
    group_kw = get_group_id_for_user(message.user)
    Group(group_kw).add(message.reply_channel)

@channel_session_user
def ws_receive(message):
    group_kw = get_group_id_for_user(message.user)
    payload = json.loads(message.content['text'])
    Channel(payload['action']).send(message.content)

@channel_session_user
def ws_disconnect(message):
    group_kw = get_group_id_for_user(message.user)
    Group(group_kw).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

That works fine, but there is a problem when testing.

The below test should place a message on the `websocket.receive` channel, then `ws_receive` should take the message and place it on the channel defined in the message's `action` value. Finally, I test if it was in fact placed on that channel.

```
def test_send_chat_message_is_used_by_consumer(self):
    # Make sure a user is authenticated
    self.assertTrue(auth.get_user(self.client).is_authenticated())

    payload = {'action': 'chat.receive',
               'msg': 'Test message.',
               'receiver': self.user2.id}
    message = {'text': json.dumps(payload)}

    # Send a chat message
    Channel('websocket.receive').send(message)
    # Receive it and place it on the right channel
    ws_receive(self.get_next_message('websocket.receive', require=True))
    # Fetch it from the channel
    result = self.get_next_message(payload['action'], require=True)
    # That should be the message sent
    self.assertEqual(result, message)
```

Instead, I get the following error, pointing to the line with the `ws_receive()` call.

> ValueError: No reply_channel sent to consumer; @channel_session can only be used on messages containing it.

The error [is raised here](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels/blob/master/channels/sessions.py#L48) in the *Channels* source.

Printing the `reply_channel` returns `None` instead of containing the correct reply channel name.

```
tmp = self.get_next_message('websocket.receive', require=True)
print(tmp.reply_channel)  # prints: None
```

I am overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot just simply call the consumer because it has the decorator `@channel_session_user`. You should try using the Client channels.tests provides.

```
from channels.tests import ChannelTestCase, Client
```

Then use something like this inside the test function

```
client = Client()
client.send('websocket.receive', content=message)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the name that you provide to the 'Channel' object represents the channel this message was received on. Check the [**init** function](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/master/channels/channel.py#L20) of Channel.

Also note the function [get_next_message](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/master/channels/tests/base.py#L59) in tests/base.py file. The *channel* parameter here refers to (reply) channel to which the message was sent to during the test.

**To answer your question** -

Look at the [docstring of Message object](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/master/channels/message.py#L10) in channels/message.py. It says,

> The message content is a dict called .content, while reply_channel is an optional extra attribute representing a channel to use to reply to this message's end user, if that makes sense.

You need to set the "reply_channel" in the dict that you send.

```
message = {
    'text': json.dumps(payload),
    'reply_channel': 'websocket.receive'
}
```

Hope it helps